# fullPage plugin resize doesn't work

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using the fullPage plugin and everything worked like expected, but then I realized, when I resize the window, there is an unwanted animation. The div container is moving and after a delay it´s getting in the desired position.

Here is my Code:

```
//HTML structure
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
    <div class="slide active">
        <div class="slide-container"></div>
        <div class ="slide-container skills"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//CSS
.section {
  text-align:center;
}

.slide-container {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.skills {
  background-color: #CDFF00;
}
```

I haven't made changes to the fullpage plugin except `loopHorizontal: false`.

Example on jsfiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/oodLzLwv/1/

Comment: Please put some code into the question and don't try and work around the restriction on embedded Fiddles. It does not gain you the assistance you require to do that. Please read [ask].

Comment: I am sorry, you are absolutely right, I made the changes.

Comment: You can't play that freely with the class `slide`as its the default selector for fullpage.js slides. Just use any custom class such as `mySlide` and apply to it any CSS you want. Fullpage.js won't touch it.

Comment: Improved indentation of code, and language, highlighted code.